# What are the alternative simple softwares for MS Paint?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-paint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a good simple free/open source photo editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/143357/looking-for-a-good-simple-free-open-source-photo-editor)
>   [Simple, native replacements for Microsoft Paint?](https://superuser.com/questions/376596/simple-native-replacements-for-microsoft-paint)

MS Paint is good but it lacks quality on some of its tools. I want to try its alternative software. Can you please give me a list of its alternatives.

I'm looking for simple software as MS Paint is. Please don't suggest me complicated software like Gimp and Photoshop. I have already tried Paint.NET, but it is too dependent on Microsoft .NET Framework, so it is very problematic to install in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple, native replacements for Microsoft Paint?](http://superuser.com/questions/376596/simple-native-replacements-for-microsoft-paint). In addition .net is preinstalled on every copy of windows, and 3.5, which is the prerequisite for paint.net is on windows 7 by default (So .net should not be an issue). I do think this question is a bit of a [shopping recommendation](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3515/since-when-are-software-recommendations-off-topic) type question.

Comment: @akira: I'm not looking for a free and open source editor. My criteria are different.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: That question is closed.

Comment: @hkBattousai: "that question is closed". exactly.

Comment: @akira For a reason which is not true.

Comment: As is this. There's no reason two *identical* questions should be treated differently. Its a *list*, which dosen't work well with the Q&A format - the choices would be *subjective* and as such not be *constructive*. Personally i *love* software rec questions, but this is really the standards we have here, in the site, at this point of time.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I understand that these types of questions aren't an excellent fit for our Q&A format, but it would have helped me and probably a whole bunch of other people if we left this question open. Also, this question was closed due to it being marked as a duplicate but this is no longer the case. The post you linked is completely gone.

Comment: Its still off topic here, and has been for years. I'd note, I closed this as a *regular* user, so 4 other users agreed to. Amusingly, that was a signficantly better question. On the other hand, there's actually a SE site where we *encourage* people to drop off a laundry list of requirements for things called software recommendations. so... meh. This should remain closed for all the same reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tongue-firmly-in-cheek]

Well, if you're looking for simple... simple to install, simple to use...

There's always [TUXPAINT](http://tuxpaint.org)

Actually has quite a nice set of features, including adding grass and various stamps which are pre-installed, with more available.  TBH, I've enjoyed many hours playing with it, as have the budding artists in my household.